# ARIA landmark role for sidebar which contains main navigation

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

The [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA11.html) suggests:

> It is a best practice to include ALL content on the page in landmarks,
>   so that screen reader users who rely on them to navigate from section
>   to section do not lose track of content.

I have a sidebar which contains the main navigation along with some other content. I have already wrapped the main navigation in a `nav` , but I am not able to decide what would be the appropriate landmark role for the sidebar.

I read up about `aside` which seems to be applicable to secondary content whether or not it is used inside an `article`.

Does it make sense to mark this sidebar as a `section` with an `aria-label="sidebar"` ? keep in mind that this sidebar contains the main navigation for the page.

Comment: What else does it contain?

Comment: For now, apart from the main navigation  it contains a button to hide the open/close the sidebar, and some other branding text/paragraph

Answer (score 0):

> The W3 suggests:

First off, be careful of terminology.  The W3 isn't necessarily saying you should put everything in a landmark.  That suggestion comes from reading [WCAG 1.3.1](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/info-and-relationships.html) and is the list of *possible* things you could do to satisfy 1.3.1 (called "[Sufficient Techniques](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/info-and-relationships.html#sufficient)").  However, by **not** doing this recommendation, you are **not** necessarily failing 1.3.1.

A code snippet of your layout might be helpful.  It's hard to follow the way you describe it but without further information, I think your `<nav>` is sufficient.